# Adding CSS element: Jquery only work when Chrome developer tools is open

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

This issue is kinda similar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918035/javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-chrome), but mine is just a simple highlighting one of the menu item by adding a CSS class.

Basically, I'm trying to loop through a list of menu item under `#nav-accordion` div. When the IF condition is true, I will append `active` class to the `li` element.

Here is my code

```
$("#nav-accordion li a").each(function () {
    if (true) {
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        // Expand the parent menu
        $(this).closest("li").closest("ul").show();
        // Highlight the parent menu item

        $(this).closest("li").parent().parent().find("a").addClass("active");

       // Exit loop when one of the menu item is highlighted
       return;
    }
}
```

When I load the page without developer tool open in Chrome, the highlight does not work; but when I open the developer tool and load the page, the highlighting work like a magic. Now I don't know how this strange magic work.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once) describe that I should remove any `console.log` in the code, which I did. But the same problem still persist.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you try to open that page in another web browser or clearing cache ?
Maybe it is a browser caching problem

Comment: I believe If(true) need to change to if(true), make the "i" lower case.

Comment: Hi @DonaldPowell Thanks for your comment but actually it was just a typo when I type the if statement. In my actual code, the if is in lower case and the condition is longer, so I just shorten it

Comment: Hi, I tried IE and Firefox, both behave in the same way as Chrome. I tried CTRL + F5 many times too, but still the same...

Comment: Try.. Right-click and Inspect Element to open the DevTools. Now click Network in the toolbar. Finally, check the Disable cache checkbox at the top

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in jQuery [$( window ).load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event. If you still get the same result try using Using [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (deferreds) or try using the setTimeout option. I had similar issue and i sorted it with jQuery.when option.